# AngularJS 1.5 - field directive for creating inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use AngularJS 1.5, I want to create a directive to make my form more easily.

I made a simple directive :

```
app.directive('fieldDirective', function($http, $compile) {

var getTemplateUrl = function(field) {
    var type = field.type;
    var templateUrl = '/assets/views/fields/';

    return templateUrl += type + '.html';
}

var linker = function(scope, element) {
    var templateUrl = getTemplateUrl(scope.field);
    $http.get(templateUrl).then(function(data) {
        element.html(data.data);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    });
}

return {
    template: '<div ng-bind="field"></div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        field: '=field',
        ngModel: "=model"
    },
    link: linker
};
```

And I made a HTML template for a field :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">
        {{  label }}
        <span class="symbol required" ng-show="field.required"></span>
    </label>

    <input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" ng-required="field.required" class="form-control">
</div>
```

I tested in a view like this :

```
<field-directive field="field" model="testForm"></field-directive>
<field-directive field="field" model="field.model"></field-directive>

{{ testForm }}
```

The **testForm** value is binded when I use "testForm" in model, but not with field.model. Here is my field :

```
$scope.field = {
    "label" : "documents.TITRE",
    "type" : "textfield",
    "model": "testForm",
    "required" : true
};
```

Can I have the model name dynamic ?

Comment: the directive has its own scope, and in order to communicate with properties from other scopes, you have to pass those properties. I cannot see that you pass this testForm anywhere in the directive.

Comment: What is `field` in your test?

Comment: mbeso ok I understand ! I though ng-model was a kind of global scope shared by all ressources.

Comment: Excellent, so give it a shot and post the results :)

Comment: Ok I've updated my question. It works, but I want to have the model name dynamic...

Comment: and why would you want that, its just variable, why have it named dynamically for different cases

Comment: That way, I can use JSON source for building my fields.

Comment: it should be working, how you know it is not binding do you print output same as for testForm? something like `{{field.model}}`

Comment: No it's not printing the same value. And doing your way causes a $parse error.

Comment: can you please post more of your controller